# Streaming multiple tweets - from multiple users? - Twitter API

Tags: php, python, twitter

I have a big list of **Twitter users** stored in a database, **almost 1000**.

I would like to use the **Streaming API** in order to **stream tweets from these users**, but I cannot find an appropriate way to do this.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is that "list" as in "twitter list" or as in "python list"?

Comment: A list stored in a database. Which can be transformed in any kind of list.

Comment: Okay. Appearantly it wouldn't matter anyway; it seems the streaming API doesn't know about lists yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Twitter API documentation](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Streaming-API-Documentation#statuses/filter), you can only use the streaming API to follow up to 400 users. For more than that, you'll have to [request an increased access level](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Streaming-API-Documentation#AccessandRateLimiting) for the account you use to access the API.

Comment: Thank you balpha, that was a very helpful answer!
Do you know if using the streaming API would affect the basic 20k req/hour?

Comment: @RadiantHex: I wouldn't think so; as far as I get it, the standard rate limits ( http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Rate-limiting ) and the streaming API limits are totally separate things. Even if that wasn't the case, it's still just one request, even if you stream for 24 hours, right? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can track 400 filter words and 5000 userids via streaming api. 
Filter words can be something apple, orange, ipad etc...
And in order to track any user's timeline you need to get the user's twitter user id.